# How to compare QVector3D or Eigen::Vector3d for equality with tolerance?

Tags: c++, boost, eigen, boost-test, qvector3d

I would like to use the `BOOST_TEST` machinery to compare mathematical vector types using plain (in)equality operators.

I can only find how to tell Boost.Test that it should do that for a type (by specializing  `boost::math::fpc::tolerance_based` for that type), given the presence of the usual arithmetic and comparison operators, but I can't tell it to do the comparison in a specific way (I'd like the element-wise comparison here, and only really need (in)equality, no less/greater etc.).

Is there any customization point for this functionality?
If not, how can I easily enable such behaviour only in my tests?

Comment: Eigen has an ```isApprox``` method that accepts an error limit https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ae8443357b808cd393be1b51974213f9c

Comment: Right,  but I want to have BOOST_TEST call that automatically when I do `BOOST_TEST(someEigenVector == MY_EXPECTED_VALUE)`, so my tests aren't riddled with specific code for comparisons when there is a test framework that implements floating point and container comparison functionality

Comment: `BOOST_TEST(((someEigenVector - targetEigenVector).array() <= tolerance).all())`...maybe.  But something like that seems far uglier than just using `isApprox`.

Comment: Yes,  but I want to write the simple equality and make BOOST_TEST use its builtin floating point/container comparison under the hood. Just like you can write BOOST_TEST(someFloat == 1.f) and it will do a tolerance-based comparison given the appropriate decorators.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a custom operator that will do the comparison.  For example:

```
bool operator == (const Vector3d &lhs, const double &rhs){
    return (lhs.array() == rhs).all();
}
```

My guess would be the authors of Eigen didn't include these because they provided the `array` class to give you access for element-wise operations.  Also there are many ways to define inequalities like this and everyone will have a different set of requirements.

Comment: Hence my question for a customization point in Boost.Test...